# An IV problem using d'Alembert's solution: how does this integration work?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'm using Roger Knobel's [An Introduction to the Mathematical Theory of Waves](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Mathematical-Theory-Student-Library/dp/0821820397) to study for a Mathematics BSc third-year module in waves. In Section 8.2, Knobel

> construct[s] the solution of the following initial value problem for the displacement $u(x,t)$ of an infinitely long vibrating string:
> \begin{align*}
> \text{PDE:}\hspace{1em}& u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}, \hspace{1em} -\infty<x<\infty,\;t>0, \\
> \text{IC:}\hspace{1em}& u(x,0)=f(x),\\&u_t(x,0)=g(x).
> \end{align*}

He continues,

> To solve this problem one can start with the general form for solutions of the wave equation $$u(x,t)=F(x-ct)+G(x+ct).$$ Substituting into the initial position condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ gives \begin{align}F(x)+G(x)=f(x),\end{align} while substituting into the initial velocity condition $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ results in $$-cF'(x)+cG'(x)=g(x).$$ Dividing this last equation by $c$ and integrating from $0$ to $x$ provides us with a second equation for $F(x)$ and $G(x)$, \begin{align}-F(x)+G(x)=-F(0)+G(0)+\frac{1}{c}\int_0^xg(s)\;\text{d}s.\end{align}

If I understand right, $F'$ and $G'$ are $t$-derivatives. So why does integrating them from $0$ to $x$ w.r.t the dummy variable $s$ retrieve $F$ and $G$, as if we'd integrated w.r.t. $t$? I guess this is a basic calculus question.

Comment: The name of a variable of integration doesn't actually matter, it's just an identifier. It only really matters when there's more than one variable involved that you could be integrating with respect to, and in this problem there isn't. Basically $s$ is "the single argument of $g$", which you could give any name you want, provided it isn't already bound in the surrounding scope. Let me know if this answers your question, I am happy to put it down as an answer.

Comment: At the level of the physics $s$ is actually a position in 1 space dimension, not a time.

Comment: @Ian Doesn't the name of a variable of integration have to match the name of a variable of differentiation, if it's going to 'cancel' it out, as in this case of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\mapsto F$? Or are we re-interpreting $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ as $\frac{\partial F}{\partial s}$? You say there isn't more than one variable we could be integrating w.r.t., but couldn't be be integrating w.r.t. to any variable at all, not necessarily an argument of any of the functions?

Comment: So first off, there's no partial derivatives once you pass to $F$ and $G$ here. The $c$'s popped out from the chain rule since you took the partial derivative wrt $t$ to begin with, but now $F,G$ and $g$ only have one argument. After that, within this one expression we can rename things however we please.

Comment: Second, you're right, you could be integrating wrt a variable that isn't the argument of the function, but then the argument would have to be something else inside the integral as the integral is written, like $\int_0^x g(y) ds$ which is a silly/confusing way of writing $xg(y)$. Here they were written to match up, since they're both $s$.

Comment: @Ian I think I've identified one of the things that was snagging me. $F'$ and $G'$ aren't $t$-derivatives as I said in my OP; they start off as $(x-ct)$- and $(x+ct)$-derivatives, respectively, which become $x$-derivatives by setting $t=0$, and at each step can be thought of as "derivatives taken wrt their respective single arguments", consistent with what you say.

Comment: Right. $F'$ and $G'$ appeared to begin with via the $t$-derivative in $u_t$, but $F$ and $G$ *themselves* do not depend on $t$. In fact they themselves don't depend on a variable with any particular name at all; keeping their argument's name consistent is a matter of style rather than being demanded by the logic. What does depend on $t$ are the *expressions* $F(x-ct)$ and $G(x+ct)$, which are what appear in the ansatz for $u(x,t)$. It's this expression/function distinction, and how it interacts with our syntax for derivatives and integrals, that is really confusing.

Comment: @Ian So the choice of $x$ as the upper limit of integration is a stylistic choice intended to preserve the name of the variable of $F$ and $G$ through the integration process, and that necessitates the choice of a different, arbitrary name for the variable of integration. I think I've got it. And $F'(x):=\left(\frac{\text{d}F}{\text{d}\cdot}(\cdot)\right)(x)$, i.e. the variable of differentiation and the argument of the derivative are given by the same single argument.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your help, this has been very useful for me. I've also learned the word 'ansatz'. If you care to write up whatever you feel like as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the name of a variable of integration doesn't actually matter, it's just an identifier. It only really matters when there's more than one variable involved that you could be integrating with respect to, and in this problem there isn't. You can think of $s$ as "the single argument of $g$", which you could give any name you want, provided it isn't already bound in the surrounding scope, so not $x,F,G,g$ or $c$. (So you could technically call it $f$, even though there is an $f$ elsewhere in the problem. Please don't, though.)

Note that the name of a variable limit of integration does matter, because the definite integral depends on that limit. Thus for example here the use of $x$ as the upper limit of integration is not a completely stylistic choice; whatever letter you use has to be the same letter that is used for the arguments of $F$ and $G$ on the LHS.

The big thing going on in the background here surrounds the difference between an expression and a function. An expression can have named variables in it. A function, strictly speaking, does not have named variables in it, it just has arguments and their positions. This means that strictly speaking a function can't be differentiated with respect to a named variable, only with respect to an argument position. But no one writes like that, unless their audience is a computer.

This results in rather convoluted things happening under the hood. For example, in this context, the symbol $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ is a shorthand for $(x_0,t_0) \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left. \left [ u(x,t) \right ] \right |_{x=x_0,t=t_0}$. Here we take $u$, a function, turn it into $u(x,t)$, an expression, turn that into $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} [u(x,t)]$, also an expression, and then finally convert that back into a function. Then we even change the name of the arguments of that function back to $(x,t)$. Similar things are going on with integration.